# Webpy template loops

Tags: python, templates, web.py

I am having a bit of trouble understanding how loop syntax should work with webpy.

I have a template with a section of code like this:

```
            $for point in slow_points:
                L.marker(${point}, {icon: slowIcon}).addTo(map);

            });
```

The `});` at the end is to close off a jquery function. Following the python indention I would expect that the `});` should not get repeated in my output page, But it does. In order to get the `});` to not get repeated I have to do it like this:

```
            $for point in slow_points:
                L.marker(${point}, {icon: slowIcon}).addTo(map);

});
```

where my `});` is all the way to the left as far as it can go, thus basically ignoring any type of indention.

Is this the expected behavior? And is there some other syntax I can use for the loop that will allow me to keep my indention "clean" but not cause the code that should be outside of the for loop block to get repeated?

Answer (score 0):

Giving your example, it really shouldn't repeat `});`. The following code

```
import web
template = """$def with(slow_points)
    $for point in slow_points:
        L.marker(${point}, {icon: slowIcon}).addTo(map);
    });
"""
page = web.template.Template(template)
print page(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Outputs this:

```
L.marker(a, {icon: slowIcon}).addTo(map);
L.marker(b, {icon: slowIcon}).addTo(map);
L.marker(c, {icon: slowIcon}).addTo(map);
});
```

Please make sure you have correct indentation style where 1 indent equals 4 spaces.